# Display a label directly on a button

Tags: swift

I see many posts explaining how to display a label after clicking on a button but it seems nobody has raised the question of how to actually display the label text directly ON the button itself.

I am coding for the AppleWatch and due to the small screen size, it would seem that saving space and actually having the label display on the button instead of above or below or to one of the sides to be something of a perfect solution.

Specifically, what I am trying to do is create a tap counter with the incrementing number be on the button itself. Tap the number (or button) and it increments by one.

Possible?

Comment: You can use auto layout to align the label's center to the button's center. What have you tried and what's your expected output?

Comment: What about updating the button's title instead of a label's text?

Comment: The only thing I have tried is actually getting the label to increment. Please note that I am extremely new to Swift. I'm taking a class and the instructor seems to have disappeared momentarily.

So, I'm a bit uneducated as to what I can try. But, it seems I can simply target and update the button text instead of the label if I understand these two responses correctly, and not worry about the label at all, correct? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a label with transparent background, and place it on top of a button.

However, this is not an ideal solution: rather than displaying a label on top of a button, you could change the text of the button itself. This way you would have the same visual effect with fewer objects on the screen:

```
button.setTitle("Text you wanted on the label", forState: .Normal)
```